How to choose alternative solution when installing CygWin?
When I try to install CygWin, one of the problems it lists is (partially) below. I 100% need certain packages, like Perl, TexLive, MySQL, Gnome Common, Evince, and FileZilla. I do not wish to throw away all those packages, just because a certain PERL package I chose is now considered obsolete. How can I choose solution 1, namely simply avoid installing the obsolete package? I don't see any command-line options that would allow me to choose, which of the two solutions I prefer.
Furthermore, suppose I ignore the message and proceed to install this obsolete package.  Might I have problems then running any of the packages that are listed below?

Problem 1/3
package gdal-3.9.0-1 obsoletes perl-gdal provided by perl-gdal-3.4.1-1
Solution 1/2

do not ask to install perl-gdal-3.4.1-1

Solution 2/2 (default)

do not ask to install gdal-3.9.0-1
do not ask to install subversion-perl-1.14.2-1
do not ask to install rxvt-unicode-9.22-6
do not ask to install postgresql-plperl-16.2-1
do not ask to install postgresql-contrib-16.2-1
do not ask to install po4a-0.71-1
do not ask to install perl_pods-5.36.3-1
do not ask to install perl_manpages-5.36.3-1
do not ask to install perl_autorebase-5.36.3-1
do not ask to install perl-zinnia-0.07-1
do not ask to install perl-YAML-Tiny-1.74-2
do not ask to install perl-YAML-LibYAML-0.89-1
do not ask to install perl-YAML-1.31-1
do not ask to install perl-XS-Parse-Keyword-0.44-1
do not ask to install perl-XML-XPath-1.48-2
do not ask to install perl-XML-Writer-0.900-3
do not ask to install perl-XML-Stream-1.24-5
do not ask to install perl-XML-Simple-2.25-4
do not ask to install perl-XML-SAX-Expat-0.51-6
do not ask to install perl-XML-SAX-Base-1.09-5
do not ask to install perl-XML-SAX-1.02-4
do not ask to install perl-XML-RegExp-0.04-6
do not ask to install perl-XML-Parser-2.47-1
do not ask to install perl-XML-NamespaceSupport-1.12-5
do not ask to install perl-XML-LibXSLT-2.003000-1
do not ask to install perl-XML-LibXML-Simple-1.01-3
do not ask to install perl-XML-LibXML-2.0210-1
do not ask to install perl-XML-DOM-1.46-5
do not ask to install perl-Xfce4-Xfconf-4.12.0-3
do not ask to install perl-Wx-build-0.9932-4
do not ask to install perl-Wx-0.9932-4
do not ask to install perl-WWW-RobotRules-6.02-9
do not ask to install perl-WWW-Curl-4.17-7
do not ask to install perl-Win32-GUI-1.14-4
do not ask to install perl-Win32-API-0.84-5
do not ask to install perl-Variable-Magic-0.64-1
do not ask to install perl-URI-5.28-1
do not ask to install perl-UNIVERSAL-require-0.19-2
do not ask to install perl-Types-Serialiser-1.01-3
do not ask to install perl-Type-Tiny-2.004000-2
do not ask to install perl-CPAN-Changes-0.500004-1
do not ask to install perl-Try-Tiny-0.31-2
do not ask to install perl-Tk-Pod-0.9943-4
do not ask to install perl-Tk-Getopt-0.51-3
do not ask to install perl-Tk-FontDialog-0.19-1
do not ask to install perl-Tk-EntryCheck-0.04-5
do not ask to install perl-Tk-ColoredButton-1.05-5
do not ask to install perl-Tk-Canvas-GradientColor-1.06-4
do not ask to install perl-Tk-804.036-2
do not ask to install perl-TimeDate-2.33-3
do not ask to install perl-Tie-Cycle-1.228-1
do not ask to install perl-Text-WrapI18N-0.06-8
do not ask to install perl-Text-Template-1.61-2
do not ask to install perl-Text-Roman-3.5-5
do not ask to install perl-Text-Glob-0.11-5
do not ask to install perl-Text-Diff-1.45-5
do not ask to install perl-Text-CSV_XS-1.56-1
do not ask to install perl-Text-CSV-2.04-1
do not ask to install perl-Text-CharWidth-0.04-7
do not ask to install perl-Text-BibTeX-0.89-2
do not ask to install perl-Test2-Suite-0.000163-1
do not ask to install perl-Test2-Plugin-NoWarnings-0.10-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-YAML-1.07-4
do not ask to install perl-Test-Without-Module-0.23-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-Warnings-0.033-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-Warn-0.37-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-utf8-1.02-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-Trap-0.3.5-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-TrailingSpace-0.0601-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-Toolbox-0.4-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-Script-1.29-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-RequiresInternet-0.05-5
do not ask to install perl-Test-Requires-0.11-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-Reporter-Transport-Metabase-1.999010-5
do not ask to install perl-Test-Reporter-1.62-6
do not ask to install perl-Test-Pod-Coverage-1.10-6
do not ask to install perl-Test-Pod-1.52-4
do not ask to install perl-Test-NoWarnings-1.06-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-NoTabs-2.02-4
do not ask to install perl-Test-Needs-0.002010-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-More-UTF8-0.05-4
do not ask to install perl-Test-MockModule-0.178.0-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-LeakTrace-0.17-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-Fork-0.02-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-File-ShareDir-1.001002-5
do not ask to install perl-Test-File-1.993-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-Fatal-0.017-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-FailWarnings-0.008-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-Exception-0.43-5
do not ask to install perl-Test-EOL-2.02-3
do not ask to install perl-Test-Differences-0.71-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-Deep-1.204-2
do not ask to install perl-Test-CPAN-Meta-0.25-5
do not ask to install perl-Test-Compile-3.3.3-1
do not ask to install perl-Test-Base-0.89-4
do not ask to install perl-TermReadKey-2.38-4
do not ask to install perl-Term-Table-0.022-1
do not ask to install perl-Term-ReadLine-Perl-1.0303-9
do not ask to install perl-Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.46-1
do not ask to install perl-Tee-0.14-9
do not ask to install perl-Syntax-Keyword-Try-0.29-1
do not ask to install perl-SUPER-1.20190531-4
do not ask to install perl-Sub-Name-0.27-1
do not ask to install perl-Sub-Install-0.929-2
do not ask to install perl-Sub-Info-0.002-5
do not ask to install perl-Sub-Identify-0.14-5
do not ask to install perl-Sub-Exporter-0.991-1
do not ask to install perl-String-Util-1.34-2
do not ask to install perl-Stow-2.4.0+5.36-1
do not ask to install perl-Spiffy-0.46-6
do not ask to install perl-Specio-0.48-2
do not ask to install perl-Sort-Versions-1.62-2
do not ask to install perl-Sort-Key-1.33-5
do not ask to install perl-solv-0.7.24-1
do not ask to install perl-SGMLSpm-1.1-3
do not ask to install perl-Scope-Guard-0.21-5
do not ask to install perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.65-1
do not ask to install perl-Role-Tiny-2.002004-3
do not ask to install perl-Regexp-Common-2024080801-1
do not ask to install perl-Readonly-XS-1.05-8
do not ask to install perl-Readonly-2.05-5
do not ask to install perl-Proc-ProcessTable-0.636-1
do not ask to install perl-Probe-Perl-0.03-7
do not ask to install perl-POD2-Base-0.043-6
do not ask to install perl-Pod-Parser-1.67-1
do not ask to install perl-Pod-Eventual-0.094003-1
do not ask to install perl-Pod-Coverage-TrustPod-0.100006-1
do not ask to install perl-Pod-Coverage-0.23-7
do not ask to install perl-PerlIO-utf8_strict-0.010-2
do not ask to install perl-Path-Tiny-0.146-1
do not ask to install perl-Path-Class-0.37-5
do not ask to install perl-Parse-RecDescent-1.967015-5
do not ask to install perl-Params-ValidationCompiler-0.31-2
do not ask to install perl-Params-Validate-1.31-2
do not ask to install perl-Params-Util-1.102-3
do not ask to install perl-PAR-Packer-1.063-1
do not ask to install perl-PAR-Dist-0.53-1
do not ask to install perl-PAR-1.020-1
do not ask to install perl-Pango-1.227-5
do not ask to install perl-PadWalker-2.5-3
do not ask to install perl-Package-Stash-XS-0.30-2
do not ask to install perl-Package-Stash-0.40-2
do not ask to install perl-Package-DeprecationManager-0.18-2
do not ask to install perl-openwsman-2.7.2-1
do not ask to install perl-OpenGL-0.7000-4
do not ask to install perl-Object-Realize-Later-0.21-4
do not ask to install perl-Number-Misc-1.2-4
do not ask to install perl-Number-Compare-0.03-9
do not ask to install perl-net-snmp-5.9.3-2
do not ask to install perl-Net-SMTP-SSL-1.04-5
do not ask to install perl-Net-Libproxy-0.4.18-1
do not ask to install perl-Net-IP-1.26-7
do not ask to install perl-Net-HTTP-6.23-1
do not ask to install perl-Net-DNS-SEC-1.26-1
do not ask to install perl-Net-DNS-1.45-1
do not ask to install perl-namespace-clean-0.27-5
do not ask to install perl-namespace-autoclean-0.29-4
do not ask to install perl-MRO-Compat-0.15-2
do not ask to install perl-Mozilla-CA-20240730-1
do not ask to install perl-Moo-2.005005-2
do not ask to install perl-Mojolicious-9.37-1
do not ask to install perl-Module-Signature-0.87-3
do not ask to install perl-Module-ScanDeps-1.35-1
do not ask to install perl-Module-Runtime-0.016-4
do not ask to install perl-Module-Install-1.21-2
do not ask to install perl-Module-Implementation-0.09-5
do not ask to install perl-Module-Build-Tiny-0.047-1
do not ask to install perl-Module-Build-0.4234-2
do not ask to install perl-Mock-Config-0.03-5
do not ask to install perl-Mixin-Linewise-0.111-1
do not ask to install perl-ming-0.4.8-4
do not ask to install perl-MIME-Types-2.26-1
do not ask to install perl-MIME-tools-5.515-1
do not ask to install perl-MIME-Charset-1.013.1-2
do not ask to install perl-MIME-Base32-1.303-5
do not ask to install perl-Metabase-Fact-0.025-5
do not ask to install perl-Metabase-Client-Simple-0.012-5
do not ask to install perl-Math-Int64-0.57-1
do not ask to install perl-marisa-0.2.4-5
do not ask to install perl-MailTools-2.21-4
do not ask to install perl-Mail-Transport-3.005-3
do not ask to install perl-Mail-Message-3.015-1
do not ask to install perl-Mail-Mbox-MessageParser-1.5111-3
do not ask to install perl-Mail-IMAPClient-3.43-2
do not ask to install perl-Mail-Box-Parser-C-3.011-1
do not ask to install perl-Mail-Box-3.010-1
do not ask to install perl-LWP-Protocol-https-6.14-1
do not ask to install perl-LWP-Online-1.08-5
do not ask to install perl-LWP-MediaTypes-6.04-4
do not ask to install perl-Log-Log4perl-1.57-2
do not ask to install perl-List-UtilsBy-0.12-2
do not ask to install perl-List-SomeUtils-XS-0.58-4
do not ask to install perl-List-SomeUtils-0.59-2
do not ask to install perl-List-MoreUtils-XS-0.430-3
do not ask to install perl-List-MoreUtils-0.430-3
do not ask to install perl-List-AllUtils-0.19-2
do not ask to install perl-Lingua-Translit-0.29-2
do not ask to install perl-libxml-perl-0.08-9
do not ask to install perl-libwww-perl-6.77-1
do not ask to install perl-Lchown-1.01-5
do not ask to install perl-JSON-XS-4.03-3
do not ask to install perl-JSON-PP-4.16-2
do not ask to install perl-JSON-Parse-0.62-2
do not ask to install perl-JSON-MaybeXS-1.004007-1
do not ask to install perl-JSON-4.10-2
do not ask to install perl-IPC-System-Simple-1.30-3
do not ask to install perl-IPC-Run3-0.049-1
do not ask to install perl-IO-Tty-1.20-1
do not ask to install perl-IO-stringy-2.113-3
do not ask to install perl-IO-String-1.08-9
do not ask to install perl-IO-Socket-INET6-2.73-2
do not ask to install perl-IO-Prompt-Tiny-0.003-6
do not ask to install perl-IO-HTML-1.004-3
do not ask to install perl-IO-CaptureOutput-1.1105-4
do not ask to install perl-Inline-Files-0.71-4
do not ask to install perl-Inline-0.86-3
do not ask to install perl-inc-latest-0.500-5
do not ask to install perl-Importer-0.026-3
do not ask to install perl-Image-Magick-7.0.10.61-1
do not ask to install perl-Image-ExifTool-12.76-1
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-Negotiate-6.01-9
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-Message-6.46-1
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-Date-6.06-1
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-Daemon-6.16-2
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-Cookies-6.11-1
do not ask to install perl-HTTP-CookieJar-0.014-1
do not ask to install perl-HTML-Tree-5.07-4
do not ask to install perl-HTML-Tagset-3.24-1
do not ask to install perl-HTML-TableExtract-2.15-5
do not ask to install perl-HTML-Parser-3.83-1
do not ask to install perl-HTML-Formatter-2.16-6
do not ask to install perl-HTML-Element-Extended-1.18-5
do not ask to install perl-gv-8.0.5-1
do not ask to install perl-Gtk3-0.038-3
do not ask to install perl-GStreamer1-0.003-5
do not ask to install perl-Graphics-Magick-1.3.40-2
do not ask to install perl-Glib-Object-Introspection-0.051-1
do not ask to install perl-Glib-1.3294-1
do not ask to install perl-gettext-1.07-5
do not ask to install perl-Getopt-ArgvFile-1.11-6
do not ask to install perl-GD-2.83-1
do not ask to install perl-Font-TTF-1.06-5
do not ask to install perl-Font-FreeType-0.16-3
do not ask to install perl-Font-AFM-1.20-5
do not ask to install perl-Finance-Quote-1.49-3
do not ask to install perl-FileHandle-Unget-0.1634-3
do not ask to install perl-File-Which-1.27-2
do not ask to install perl-File-TreeCreate-0.0.1-2
do not ask to install perl-File-Slurper-0.014-2
do not ask to install perl-File-Slurp-Tiny-0.004-5
do not ask to install perl-File-Slurp-9999.32-3
do not ask to install perl-File-ShareDir-Install-0.14-2
do not ask to install perl-File-ShareDir-1.118-3
do not ask to install perl-File-Remove-1.61-2
do not ask to install perl-File-pushd-1.016-4
do not ask to install perl-File-Listing-6.16-1
do not ask to install perl-File-HomeDir-1.006-3
do not ask to install perl-File-Find-Rule-0.34-5
do not ask to install perl-File-Find-Object-Rule-0.0313-2
do not ask to install perl-File-Find-Object-0.3.8-1
do not ask to install perl-File-Copy-Recursive-0.45-4
do not ask to install perl-File-chdir-0.1011-3
do not ask to install perl-FFI-CheckLib-0.31-2
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-XSpp-0.18-6
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-LibBuilder-0.08-5
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-InstallPaths-0.013-1
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-Helpers-0.027-1
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-F77-1.26-2
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-Depends-0.8001-2
do not ask to install perl-ExtUtils-Config-0.009-1
do not ask to install perl-Exporter-Tiny-1.006002-2
do not ask to install perl-Exception-Class-1.45-2
do not ask to install perl-Eval-Closure-0.14-5
do not ask to install perl-Error-0.17029-3
do not ask to install perl-Encode-Locale-1.05-5
do not ask to install perl-Encode-compat-0.07-6
do not ask to install perl-Dist-CheckConflicts-0.11-6
do not ask to install perl-Digest-SHA1-2.13-9
do not ask to install perl-Digest-HMAC-1.04-2
do not ask to install perl-Digest-GOST-0.06-5
do not ask to install perl-Digest-BubbleBabble-0.02-7
do not ask to install perl-Devel-Symdump-2.18-5
do not ask to install perl-Devel-StackTrace-2.05-1
do not ask to install perl-Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.14-5
do not ask to install perl-Devel-CheckLib-1.16-2
do not ask to install perl-Devel-Autoflush-0.06-6
do not ask to install perl-DBI-1.643-3
do not ask to install perl-DBD-SQLite-1.74-1
do not ask to install perl-DBD-mysql-4.052-1
do not ask to install perl-DateTime-TimeZone-2.62-1
do not ask to install perl-DateTime-Locale-1.43-1
do not ask to install perl-DateTime-1.65-1
do not ask to install perl-Date-Simple-3.03-6
do not ask to install perl-Date-Manip-6.95-1
do not ask to install perl-Data-UUID-1.227-1
do not ask to install perl-Data-Uniqid-0.12-5
do not ask to install perl-Data-OptList-0.114-1
do not ask to install perl-Data-GUID-0.051-2
do not ask to install perl-Data-Dump-1.25-2
do not ask to install perl-Data-Diver-1.0101-7
do not ask to install perl-Data-Compare-1.29-2
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-RSA-0.33-3
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Random-0.17-1
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Guess-0.15-3
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-EC-1.32-4
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-DSA-0.20-3
do not ask to install perl-Crypt-OpenSSL-Bignum-0.09-5
do not ask to install perl-Cpanel-JSON-XS-4.38-1
do not ask to install perl-CPAN-Testers-Report-1.999003-6
do not ask to install perl-CPAN-Reporter-1.2019-1
do not ask to install perl-CPAN-Meta-Check-0.018-1
do not ask to install perl-CPAN-DistnameInfo-0.12-9
do not ask to install perl-Config-Tiny-2.30-1
do not ask to install perl-Config-AutoConf-0.320-2
do not ask to install perl-Compress-Bzip2-2.28-3
do not ask to install perl-common-sense-3.75-3
do not ask to install perl-Clone-0.46-2
do not ask to install perl-clinkgrammar-5.12.3-1
do not ask to install perl-Class-XSAccessor-1.19-7
do not ask to install perl-Class-Tiny-1.008-3
do not ask to install perl-Class-Singleton-1.6-3
do not ask to install perl-Class-Method-Modifiers-2.15-2
do not ask to install perl-Class-Inspector-1.36-4
do not ask to install perl-Class-Factory-Util-1.7-5
do not ask to install perl-Class-Data-Inheritable-0.09-2
do not ask to install perl-Class-Accessor-0.51-4
do not ask to install perl-Chemistry-OpenBabel-3.1.1p36-4
do not ask to install perl-CGI-4.66-1
do not ask to install perl-Capture-Tiny-0.48-4
do not ask to install perl-Canary-Stability-2013-4
do not ask to install perl-Cairo-GObject-1.005-3
do not ask to install perl-Cairo-1.109-3
do not ask to install perl-Business-ISSN-1.005-2
do not ask to install perl-Business-ISBN-Data-20240807.001-1
do not ask to install perl-Business-ISBN-3.009-1
do not ask to install perl-Barcode-ZBar-0.23.1-1
do not ask to install perl-B-Hooks-EndOfScope-0.28-1
do not ask to install perl-B-Generate-1.56-4
do not ask to install perl-B-COW-0.007-2
do not ask to install perl-autovivification-0.18-4
do not ask to install perl-Authen-SASL-XS-1.00-5
do not ask to install perl-Authen-SASL-2.1700-1
do not ask to install perl-Astro-FITS-CFITSIO-1.18-1
do not ask to install perl-Archive-Zip-1.68-3
do not ask to install perl-Archive-Extract-0.88-2
do not ask to install perl-App-XML-DocBook-Builder-0.1101-1
do not ask to install perl-Alien-wxWidgets-0.69-4
do not ask to install perl-Alien-Libxml2-0.19-2
do not ask to install perl-Alien-CFITSIO-4.4.0.2-1
do not ask to install perl-Alien-Build-Plugin-Download-GitLab-0.01-2
do not ask to install perl-Alien-Build-2.83-1
do not ask to install perl-Algorithm-Diff-1.2010-3
do not ask to install perl-Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27-4
do not ask to install perl-5.36.3-1
do not ask to install nginx-mod_http_perl-1.24.0-1
do not ask to install net-snmp-agent-libs-5.9.3-2
do not ask to install irssi-1.4.5-1
do not ask to install hexchat-perl-2.16.1-1
do not ask to install biber-2.19-2
do not ask to install git-email-2.45.1-1
do not ask to install snownews-1.5.12-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-bibtexextra-20240312-1
do not ask to install svn_load_dirs-1.9.2-2
do not ask to install libexo1_0-0.10.7-1
do not ask to install cygport-0.36.9-1
do not ask to install grepmail-5.3033-7
do not ask to install texlive-collection-binextra-20240312-1
do not ask to install libcurl-devel-8.9.1-1
do not ask to install icoutils-0.32.3-1
do not ask to install html2ps-1.0b7-2
do not ask to install a2ps-4.14-3
do not ask to install xhtml2ps-1.0b7-2
do not ask to install texlive-collection-basic-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-basic-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-context-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-context-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-fontsextra-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-fontsextra-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-fontutils-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-fontutils-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-formatsextra-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-games-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-humanities-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-humanities-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-langenglish-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-latex-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-latex-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-latexextra-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-latexextra-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-latexrecommended-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-luatex-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-luatex-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-mathscience-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-metapost-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-music-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-music-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-pictures-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-pictures-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-plaingeneric-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-plaingeneric-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-pstricks-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-pstricks-doc-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-publishers-20240312-1
do not ask to install texlive-collection-xetex-20240312-1
do not ask to install asymptote-2.88-1
do not ask to install libkpathsea-devel-20240312-1
do not ask to install libkpathsea6-20240312-1
do not ask to install libptexenc-devel-20240312-1
do not ask to install libptexenc1-20240312-1
do not ask to install libsynctex-devel-20240312-1
do not ask to install libsynctex2-20240312-1
do not ask to install libtexlua53-devel-20240312-1
do not ask to install libtexlua53_5-20240312-1
do not ask to install libtexluajit-devel-20240312-1
do not ask to install libtexluajit2-20240312-1
do not ask to install xmltoman-0.4-2
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-glibmm2.4-2.54.1-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-glibmm2.4-2.54.1-1
do not ask to install libglibmm2.4-devel-2.54.1-2
do not ask to install intltool-0.51.0-1
do not ask to install kde-dev-scripts-23.03.80-1
do not ask to install moreutils-0.67-1
do not ask to install unifont-viewer-15.1.05-1
do not ask to install mysql-bench-10.3.14-1
do not ask to install gnucash-2.6.21-1
do not ask to install sleuthkit-perl-4.12.1-2
do not ask to install mysql-10.3.14-1
do not ask to install gitweb-2.45.1-1
do not ask to install dblatex-0.3.12-2
do not ask to install xfdesktop-4.12.3-1
do not ask to install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin-1.7.3-1
do not ask to install xfce4-settings-4.12.1-1
do not ask to install xfce4-screenshooter-plugin-1.8.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-screenshooter-1.8.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-places-plugin-1.7.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-panel-4.12.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-mpc-plugin-0.4.5-1
do not ask to install xfce4-mailwatch-plugin-1.2.0-4
do not ask to install xfce4-clipman-plugin-1.2.6-1
do not ask to install Thunar-1.6.10-2
do not ask to install libexo1-devel-0.10.7-1
do not ask to install exo-0.10.7-1
do not ask to install preview-latex-13.3-1
do not ask to install librasqal-devel-0.9.33-1
do not ask to install libabiword3.0-devel-3.0.2-3
do not ask to install librdf-devel-1.0.17-2
do not ask to install libslv2-devel-0.6.6-5
do not ask to install libraptor2-devel-2.0.15-1
do not ask to install liblrdf-devel-0.5.0-2
do not ask to install libproj-devel-9.4.0-1
do not ask to install liboauth-devel-1.0.3-1
do not ask to install libgdata-devel-0.17.9-1
do not ask to install gnome-exe-thumbnailer-0.9.3-1
do not ask to install gnucash-devel-2.6.21-1
do not ask to install xmlto-0.0.28-1
do not ask to install gtk-doc-1.33.2-1
do not ask to install gnome-common-3.18.0-1
do not ask to install mate-common-1.20.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-dev-tools-4.12.0-1
do not ask to install asciidoc-10.2.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-session-4.12.1-1
do not ask to install xfce4-xkb-plugin-0.7.1-1
do not ask to install xfce4-wmdock-plugin-0.6.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-weather-plugin-0.8.8-1
do not ask to install xfce4-verve-plugin-1.0.1-1
do not ask to install xfce4-timer-plugin-1.6.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-time-out-plugin-1.0.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin-0.4.6-1
do not ask to install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin-0.2.4-1
do not ask to install xfce4-panel-devel-4.12.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-notes-plugin-1.8.1-1
do not ask to install xfce4-indicator-plugin-2.3.4-1
do not ask to install xfce4-genmon-plugin-3.4.0-2
do not ask to install xfce4-fsguard-plugin-1.0.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-eyes-plugin-4.4.5-1
do not ask to install xfce4-equake-plugin-1.3.8-1
do not ask to install xfce4-embed-plugin-1.6.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-dict-plugin-0.7.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-cpugraph-plugin-1.0.5-2
do not ask to install xfce4-calculator-plugin-0.6.0-1
do not ask to install orage-4.12.1-2
do not ask to install Thunar-devel-1.6.10-2
do not ask to install latexila-3.26.1-1
do not ask to install latex2rtf-2.3.17-1
do not ask to install docbook-utils-0.6.14-2
do not ask to install doxygen-latex-1.10.0-1
do not ask to install texinfo-tex-7.1-1
do not ask to install cantor-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install lilypond-2.24.3-1
do not ask to install emacs-auctex-13.3-1
do not ask to install icon-naming-utils-0.8.90-1
do not ask to install xdg-utils-1.1.1-2
do not ask to install libxml++2.6-devel-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install libpangomm1.4-devel-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install libgtksourceviewmm3.0-devel-3.18.0-1
do not ask to install libgtkmm3.0-devel-3.22.2-1
do not ask to install libgtkmm2.4-devel-2.24.5-1
do not ask to install libgoocanvasmm2.0-devel-1.90.11-1
do not ask to install libgnomevfsmm2.6-devel-2.26.0-1
do not ask to install libgnomeuimm2.6-devel-2.28.0-1
do not ask to install libgdamm5.0-devel-4.99.11-1
do not ask to install libgconfmm2.6-devel-2.28.2-2
do not ask to install libatkmm1.6-devel-2.24.2-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-pangomm1.4-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libxml++2.6-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libgnomeuimm2.6-2.28.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libgnomemm2.6-2.28.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libgnomecanvasmm2.6-2.26.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libglademm2.4-2.6.7-3
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-libgdamm5.0-4.99.8-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-gtksourceviewmm3.0-3.18.0-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-gtkmm3.0-3.22.2-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-gtkmm2.4-2.24.5-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-goocanvasmm2.0-1.90.11-1
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-gnome-vfsmm2.6-2.26.0-2
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-gconfmm2.6-2.28.2-2
do not ask to install mingw64-i686-atkmm1.6-2.24.2-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-pangomm1.4-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libxml++2.6-2.40.1-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libgnomeuimm2.6-2.28.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libgnomemm2.6-2.28.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libgnomecanvasmm2.6-2.26.0-3
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libglademm2.4-2.6.7-3
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-libgdamm5.0-4.99.8-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-gtksourceviewmm3.0-3.18.0-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-gtkmm3.0-3.22.2-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-goocanvasmm2.0-1.90.11-1
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-gnome-vfsmm2.6-2.26.0-2
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-gconfmm2.6-2.28.2-2
do not ask to install mingw64-x86_64-atkmm1.6-2.24.2-1
do not ask to install libgeotiff-devel-1.7.3-1
do not ask to install libevdocument3_4-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install atril-1.20.1-1
do not ask to install cantor-devel-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-r-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-qalculate-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-python3-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-octave-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-maxima-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-lua-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install cantor-backend-kalgebra-17.12.3-1
do not ask to install libgnomemm2.6-devel-2.28.0-1
do not ask to install libgnomecanvasmm2.6-devel-2.26.0-1
do not ask to install libglademm2.4-devel-2.6.7-11
do not ask to install nautilus-evince-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install libevview3_3-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install libevince3-devel-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install girepository-Evince3.0-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install evince-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install caja-document-properties-1.20.1-1
do not ask to install atril-devel-1.20.1-1
do not ask to install gnome-flashback-3.26.0-1
do not ask to install xfce4-dict-common-0.7.2-1
do not ask to install xfce4-dict-0.7.2-1
do not ask to install plasma-sdk-5.8.9-1
do not ask to install grace-5.1.25-3
do not ask to install filezilla-3.27.0-1
do not ask to install ddd-3.4.0-1
do not ask to install grace-devel-5.1.25-3


Install MobaXterm, configure it with specific root and home and then install required packages

I am installing CygWin right now...  If I get what you're saying, you're telling me to ignore the suggestion (i.e. install the obsolete package), and after everything is done to install MobaXTerm?

No, download MobaXterm (it is actually CygWin environments) and inside install the packages you need.

I just took a look -- will it provide the .exe files that I can run in Windows without having Cygwin up, like Cygwin does?  From the description it looks like it will be a fully remote terminal, without storing the executable files in the Windows filesystem...

Correct. You have also some python, perl plugins with some packages inside. But you can install (almost) any package with command apt install package_name :) But you need to configure to have dedicated root and home places!

MobaXTerm 100% AND NOT JUST FOR THIS.  Not that this helps.. but I ended up using WSL/Ubuntu for 99% (when possible) because of the package madness.  It just works and isn't a port.
